# How to add up multiple values for multiple rows in excel and end up with 1 row per unique ID with sums in columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

Basically I have a huge list of data with multiple rows of unique IDs (each ID can appear on multiple rows). I then have multiple variables in no particular order associated with a value. I would like to consolidate everything in to a single row for each unique ID with columns for each variable and the sum of the values.

See dummy dataset here http://www.filedropper.com/help_1

Final format should be

Unique ID Variable_X Variable_Y Variable_Z
1
2
3
4
5

With the sum of each variable in the associated column

I have a tried a few methods such as transposing or trying to concatenate variable to the unique ID. Manually I can easily do it with filters but I have 1000s of unique IDs and would like to speed up the process. While I am learning python and VBA I am not close to being able to solve this!

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of editing on some old code I had lying around. You could try if this works for you:

```vbs
Sub IDsort()
Dim list As Range, c As Range, nxt As Long
Set list = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A2"), Range("A65000").End(xlUp))
For Each c In list
    If Not ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row).Value = c.Value Then nxt = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Range("E" & nxt).Value = c
    Select Case UCase(c.Offset(0, 1))
        Case "X"
            Range("F" & nxt).Value = Range("F" & nxt).Value + c.Offset(0, 2)
        Case "Y"
            Range("G" & nxt).Value = Range("G" & nxt).Value + c.Offset(0, 2)
        Case "Z"
            Range("H" & nxt).Value = Range("H" & nxt).Value + c.Offset(0, 2)
    End Select

Next c
End Sub
```

This goes through the list, and adds up all the numbers for each variable present, and prints them in column `E` to `H`.
This requires the list to be sorted on ID, since there's only a check to see if we are on the same ID for each row, rather than what specific ID that is.

**How it works:**

So first, we set the `list` variable to be the first row of values, to the last row.
Then we loop through all the cells in a `for each` loop. The variable `c`in this case will return the value of the cell.

Then the `If` checks if the previous entry in column `E` is the same as  the current ID, and if not, `nxt` will point to the next empty row.
This is supposed to return `FALSE`on the first run (I assume an empty list), otherwise the code will fail, due to the variable `nxt` not having a value.
I figured this wouldn't be an issue, but can be easily fixed by declaring `nxt = 2` before the loop.

Then it puts the ID in Column `E`, and depending on the variable, adds the value in column `C`  to either `F`, `G` or `H`.

**This is the result when I run it on your example workbook:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! One small issue is that it seems to miss some values. For instance uniqueID 3 value for Z should be 125 (50+75)

Comment: Yeah, it's way off. I forgot to Edit the last part in each case after copying. So Y and Z were completely broken. It should work fine now.